# How do I remove a CSS class from a jqGrid cell?

Tags: css, jqgrid

It is possible to add a CSS class to a jqGrid cell using the setCell method as below.

```
grid.setCell(rowId, "ColumnName", "", "my-style-class");
```

Considering that this method appears only able to **add** CSS classes, how can one **remove** a CSS class from a jqGrid cell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One can't remove the call class with a standard jqGrid method. So you have to do this manually:

```
var iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid,"ColumnName"),
    tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(rowid), // grid is defined as grid=$("#grid_id")
    td = tr.cells[iCol];
$(td).removeClass("my-style-class");
```

where `getColumnIndexByName` is a simple function which get the column index by the column name:

```js
var getColumnIndexByName = function(grid,columnName) {
    var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
    for (var i=0,l=cm.length; i<l; i++) {
        if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
            return i; // return the index
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithRemoveCellClass.htm).

**UPDATED**: [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) have `iColByName` internal parameter which can be used instead of `getColumnIndexByName` function. The `iColByName` parameter will be filled by free jqGrid internally and it will updated by reodering of columns. So it's safe to use

```js
var p = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"), // get the reference to all parameters
    iCol = p.iColByName["ColumnName"], // get index by column name
    cm = p.colModel[iCol]; // item of "ColumnName" column
```

The way is very simple and it works very quickly. One should take in consideration that the feature is included in free jqGrid *after* publishing of free jqGrid 4.8. So one have to download the latest sources from GitHub or to use at least free jqGrid 4.9-beta1 to have the feature.

Answer (score 1):

One can easily add new class to a cell by removing the old class as:

```javascript
$("#gridname").removeClass('oldclass')
              .setCell(rowId,'column_name','','newclass');
```

Where `rowId` is id of the row containing corresponding cell and can be obtained as:

```javascript
var ids = $("#gridname").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
```