# Remove/Add class to jqgrid row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I add class to row base on condition in rowattr.I add action button in grid and when click on action must be  remove 'class1' of current row and add 'class2'.
how to do this?

```
$("#gridParaf").jqGrid(
{
    url: "GetLetterInformationHandler.ashx?CurrentUser=" + 1457,
        datatype: 'json',
        colNames: ['action', 'IAnsDateTime', 'IAnsState'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'IAnsDateTime', width: 50, sortable: false, hidden: false, template: CenterTemplate },
            { name: 'IAnsState', width: 20, sortable: false, hidden: false, template: CenterTemplate },
            { name: 'SysCode', width: 20, sortable: false, hidden: true,key:true },
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        loadonce: true,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20],
        recordpos: "left",
        rowattr: function (rd) {
            var viewDate = grid.getGridParam("userData")[rd["SysCode"]]["IAnsDateTime"];
            return { "class": (viewDate == '') ? "class1" : "class2" };
        },
        loadComplete: function() {
            $("<div>", {
                    title: "I like it",
                    mouseover: function() {
                        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                    },
                    mouseout: function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                    },
                    click: function(e) {
                        window.rowData = grid.getGridParam("userData")[$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")];
                    }
                }
            ).css({ "margin-right": "10px", "float": "left", cursor: "pointer" })
                .append('<span class="ui-icon icon-Confirm "></span>')
                .prependTo($(this).children("div"));
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346323/how-do-i-remove-a-css-class-from-a-jqgrid-cell)

```
var tr = window.grid[0].rows.namedItem(window.selectedRow);
$(tr).removeClass("class1");
$(tr).addClass("class2");
```