# Remove jqGrid editoptions from a Column

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jqgrid

In my jqGrid, the onSelect function I set dataEvent on a particular column if the column cell is not an empty string.

As long as I edit a row where the particular cell has a value the dataEvent does not get set on the column. This is desired behavior.

Again if I edit a row where the cell is blank and the dataEvent is bound to the column. Again this is desired behavior.

However, once the second senerio is performed the dataevent seems locked to the column even when the check cell has a value.

My onSelect code:

```
function oSelect(id){
var vjobno = "";
vjobno = $("#timesheetlineitemsqueue").getRowData(id)['jobno'];
$("#timesheetlineitemsqueue").setColProp('date', { editoptions: {    dataUrl: '/TimeSheetWebApp/TimeSheetControllerServlet?lifecycle=weekdayoptions'}});
        $("#timesheetlineitemsqueue").setColProp('deptno', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/TimeSheetWebApp/TimeSheetControllerServlet?lifecycle=departmentoptions'}});              
        $("#timesheetlineitemsqueue").setColProp('iphase', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/TimeSheetWebApp/TimeSheetControllerServlet?lifecycle=phaseoptions'}});
        $("#timesheetlineitemsqueue").setColProp('icategory', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/TimeSheetWebApp/TimeSheetControllerServlet?lifecycle=categoryoptions'}});
        if(vjobno == ""){
            $("#timesheetlineitemsqueue").setColProp('jobno', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'click', fn: function(e) {resetvalidation(this.name);  }},{ type: 'focus', fn: function(e) {resetvalidation(this.name);  }},{ type: 'change', fn: function(e) {validatejobnumber(this.value);  }},]}});
        }           
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand that `getGridParam` returns **the reference** to internal parameters used by jqGrid. Thus you can use for example

```
var p = $("#timesheetlineitemsqueue").jqGrid("getGridParam");
```

and access to `colModel` using `p.colModel`. Alternatively you can use

```
var colModel = $("#timesheetlineitemsqueue").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
```

to get the reference to `colModel` array.

To get the column item, which have the name `jobno`, one can use `iColByName` in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). Then

```
var cm = p.colModel[p.iColByName.jobno];
```

If you use some old version of jqGrid instead of free jqGRid then you can find the index of `jobno` in the loop (see the code of `getColumnIndexByName` in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348120/315935) for example).

Now you can set any property of `cm` item without usage `setColProp`. In the same way you can use `delete` to delete the property. For example

```
delete cm.editoptions.dataEvents;
```

Comment: I am using jqGrid  4.6.0.

Comment: @SteveDyke: Then you can use `getColumnIndexByName` function instead of `iColByName`. In general I would recommend you to consider to migrate to more new version [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.11.1, which I develop, or to alternative fork [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) 5.0.1, which develop Tony Tomov. The upgrade is not directly connected to your current question.

Comment: I have downloaded 4.12 but when I look at the source I have several errors showing up mainly at the default: code instances. Here is the error message: Multiple markers at this line
 - Missing semicolon
 - The default case is already 
  defined
 - Missing semicolon

Comment: @SteveDyke: Could you be exact please? If you fond an error in the source code of free jqGrid then please write where exactly, in which line? I included jshint and jscs in the build of free jqGrid (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/gruntfile.js)), thus the errors like Missing semicolon can't exist. If you have some problems in your code after the upgrade (some compatibility errors), then you can post the demo which shows the problems. I would try to help you to fix the problems.

Comment: Sorry it has taken so long to respond. I do not think it is a code error but a bug maybe. In the jqgrid files where ever there is a switch case statement I get an error that default case is already defined. I am using Webshphere 8.0 which is built on Eclipse.

Comment: @SteveDyke: Sorry, but I can't follow you. You write about "a code error" without posting any code. Which "switch case statement" you mean later? You should just post the exact details, what you mean. You can prepare the demo which use non-minimized free jqGrid 4.12.0 and describe the test case. If you write about some error in some switch case statement then you should at least post the link to the corresponding line of the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/tree/v4.12.0/js).