# How do i return custom formatter in my JQGrid using getGridParam?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
var p = this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), cm = p.colModel
```

I am able to get the colModel but I had certain custom formatters defined in the model which are not getting returned.

```
{name:'HTML_DEVICE_CNT',index:'HTML_DEVICE_CNT', width:35, align:"center",editable:true, sortable: false,formatter:deviceDetailsPopup,resizable:false,hidden:hiddenDevice},
{name:'edit',index:'edit', width:20, align:"center",editable:true, sortable: false,formatter:contactDetailsPopup,resizable:false},
```

How can I get getGridParam to return the custom formatter also?

Comment: This is more of how do I get a key value for a specific item in a dictionary from a array of objects in a javascript because p.colModel, would give you an array of objects which each object is a dictionary with a formatter key. So p.colModel[0].formatter would give the formatter for the first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on the fork of jqGrid, which you use. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) contains `iColByName` parameter, which simplify getting the item of `colModel` by the name. Thus you can us the code like

```js
var p = this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), cm = p.colModel, iColByName = p.iColByName;
var formatter1 = cm[iColByName.HTML_DEVICE_CNT].formatter;
var formatter2 = cm[iColByName.edit].formatter;
```

If you have the column name in the variable `cmName` then you can use

```js
var formatter3 = cm[iColByName[cmName]].formatter;
```

If you have to use an old version of jqGrid then you need to make a loop over all items of `cm` array and compare the `name` property of every item with the column name, which you look for (`"edit"` or `"HTML_DEVICE_CNT"`). See the function `getColumnIndexByName` from [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348120/315935) for example.